# How to change direction of div like table in html

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need to change the direction of my div tag to right-to-left like table.
when we change direction of a table then it changes columns order. 
I need this action to do on div tag. This action is necessary when I switch to other language like `persian, arabic...` then the layout need to change their places from `right to left`.

Here is my code :

```
<div style="direction: rtl; display: block; ">
    <div style="display: inline">
        My</div>
    <div style="display: inline">
        name</div>
    <div style="display: inline">
        is</div>
    <div style="display: inline">
        mojtaba</div>
</div>
```

Notice that before I used  `display:table` & `display:table-cell` and it was perfect as what I desired but the problem with that this code is limited to some new version browsers as http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html stated that. So somehow I need to figure a way to fix above codes as I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Old-school-no-CSS is still valid in HTML4. I think also in HTML5... Use it:

```
<table dir="rtl">
 ...
</table>
```

Comment: Then change the float direction (float:left->float:right) by adding another CSS when in RTL mode

Comment: @Elcuco, thanks - works great with table based on DIV elements.

Comment: @PiotrStępniewski be warned - are you looking for layout of just ordering the text direction? If the text inside your div origins from user input it may not always be "RTL". You need to detect this on runtime, not... "compile time". Also note that english in RTL elements will look weird (punctuation will be out of order).